# How to keep track of MailCore operations

Tags: objective-c, imap, mailcore2

I'm trying to build an OS X mail client using `MailCore2`, and I need to know what current operations are currently running, and in what state they are — think Mail.app activity monitor window.

I've some things that I could use in the API : The `MCOIMAPSession` object has a `operationQueueRunningChangeBlock` property, but it only tells me when the session changes states (running => not running) but that is insufficient.

Right now I think I'll have to subclass/wrap those to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

MailCore does not provide an API to track running operations, nor should we, because that is your job.  A typical pattern to implement this would be to either subclass the operation classes to tag each one with some kind of activity object, or aggregate activities in a separate queue and push and pop as operations are enqueued and dequeued respectively.  The completion blocks of each request in the Objective-C interface should provide enough of the state of each operation for you, and some [specific kinds](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/src/objc/smtp/MCOSMTPSendOperation.h) of operations even include progress blocks/hooks.